# Why do some stars have a border on them?

Tags: support, chat, chat-stars

In chat, most often the stars are entirely black. But sometimes I see a white star which has a black border. As I saw, they leave the messages for a long time in the starboard. Are those white stars featured? Who can add one?

Comment: The white stars are pinned messages. Only room owners and moderators can pin messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Room owners and moderators can "pin" posts. This shows a black-bordered star in the log, unless the message is actually starred by users. (Unless you are among the users who have starred it; then you will see a black-bordered yellow star.)

See also:

[image: look at the stars]

Comment: Yayaya good thanks :)